# Grab Random record from SQL Database and display it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm on Rails 4 using SQLite, and I have a database of 75,000 quotes. I would like to grab a random record (quote) from this database and display it for users to see. I've looked around but no method I have searched around here has worked yet. Here's code that grabs the first record and displays it:

```
<% Quote.limit(1).all.each do |quote| %>
<%= quote.quote %> :: <%= quote.author %> :: <%= quote.genre %>
```

I have also tried the following method, but this returns a long alphanumeric value  rather than the quote.

```
offset = rand(Quote.count)
rand_record = Quote.offset(offset).first
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's quite unclear why your 2nd snippet would return alphanumeric values.

Anyway in SQLite you have random() available so you can `order by random() limit 1`

Comment: @BookOfGreg I'm very unexperienced in the field, so where exactly would I put `order by random() limit 1` ? Also what would the code look like in in my main view, syntax wise. Thanks so much.

Comment: Your original solution is correct. Philip is right that the alphanum issue you saw is due to you inspecting the object rather than outputting it's values.
If you do want to order_by random() it would be similar to  `Quote.order_by("random()").limit(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not `order by random()` in your SQL call.  It's extremely inefficient as your database has to call the random function for each row, assign it a value, then sort on it.  As the number of rows grows this becomes very slow.

Your second method should work and is a much better solution.  I tried it with my own database and it works.  `rand_record` will be a `Quote` object -- not the quote string itself.  I would do this:

In your controller action:

```
random_offset = rand(Quote.count - 1)
@random_quote = Quote.offset(random_offset).first
```

In your view:

```
<%= @random_quote.quote %> :: <%= @random_quote.author %> :: <%= @random_quote.genre %>
```

The reason we subtract one from the count is that if we choose an offset that is the same as the number of Quote records then our call to fetch will be nil as the query's offset is one too many.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I do this I get "undefined method `quote' for nil:NilClass" in an action controller error. Any ideas? Sorry I'm new to this all.

Comment: Nevermind! Played around with it and it works, thanks so much @PhilipHallstrom